# updating/ adding json data in mysql

Tags: mysql, arrays, json

In this table - `table` I have a column - `id` and its content is as follows: `{"id": [1,2,3]}`

My question is there a way to append new value to array in JSON object in this column?
For example:

1. If I have this new value - `4` I want my `id` column value to become - `{"id": [1,2,3,4]}`
2. if I have this new value array - `[4,5,6]` I want my "id" column value to become - `{"id": [1,2,3,4,5,6]}`.

any idea how can I solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test (value JSON)
> SELECT '{"id": [1,2,3]}' value;
> SELECT CAST(value AS CHAR) FROM test;
> SELECT JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE(value, '{"id": [4]}') FROM test;
> SELECT JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE(value, '{"id": [4, 5, 6]}') FROM test;
> ```
>
> ```
> | CAST(value AS CHAR) |
> | :------------------ |
> | {"id": [1, 2, 3]}   |
>
> | JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE(value, '{"id": [4]}') |
> | :---------------------------------------- |
> | {"id": [1, 2, 3, 4]}                      |
>
> | JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE(value, '{"id": [4, 5, 6]}') |
> | :---------------------------------------------- |
> | {"id": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]}                      |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0d899da0237a5ae4cb3f998e00317ac2)*